# Sharepoint Audit Data Incorrect - Showing multiple View interaction instead of a single one

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2016, audit-log-reports

I am facing an issue with the Sharepoint Corporate 2016 I have.

When looking at the reporting part which is Placeholder_Audit_Log_2020-07-31T021700.xlsx, I have the following dataset:

[image: Dataset]

As you can see, when a single user goes to my Sharepoint, it will create a view event for all the different reports on the Sharepoint (at 1 sec timing) which does not make sense for reporting purpose and the data as such is incorrect. I confirmed it with myself as benchmark, it shows that I accessed all reports on the Sharepoint in a single visit when it is not the case at all and I only viewed one report.

Here is my configuration as of today:

[image: Sharepoint settings]

Do I need to create a list for each one of the .pdf, .xlsx file I put in the Sharepoint to have a proper reporting? or am I missing something?

I have very little experience with Sharepoint, I am just using it to share my reports with stakeholders so if it needs some advanced tweaking, I would appreciate any walkthrough.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

When you select an event to audit for a site collection, the report will audit every item in the site collection each time the event occurs.

Per my test, it's the same result with you, I think this is the default design for the audit log report.

[image]

[image]